# Meaning and usage of ‘scharch’

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I have been reading [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/) in German, via [xkcDE](https://xkcde.dapete.net/). I was reading [this one](https://xkcde.dapete.net/670/), and was very confused by a word in the third panel, ‘scharch’. It’s clearly to show that the character is bored; in the original the character just says ‘zzzzz’. But is this a common word in German; is it dialectical or regional? Does it have any meaning besides how it’s used in the comic, as an interjection?

I’ve Googled this term, and looked in a German dictionary, but I can’t find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: It's a typo.

The correct word is "schnarch", which is the inflective/onomatopoeian form of

> schnarchen - to snore

Inflective forms (sometimes called [Erikativ](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflektiv)) are often used in comics. As in the [original comic](https://xkcd.com/670/) it's used to show, that the person is sleeping/is bored.

Comment: Oh, I see — thank you, for both the information and the links.